# IntelliJ: Shortcut for seeing usages of (the routines of) an imported class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In Java, if you want to use the classes of another package in your class `A`, you do

```
import mypackage.B;
import mypackage.C;
```

In IntelliJ, is there a built-in way of selecting `B` in the import line above and see all the occurences of `B`'s routines in the current class `A`?

Comment: My work around- ALT-F7 (Search usages) and then in the report Group By File Structure.

Comment: yeah. bit tedious though for large projects.

Comment: What makes it tedious?  That's how you search for symbols in IntelliJ.

Comment: well that lists all the usages in all modules in my project. I will have to manually go up and down to get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the cursor on the `import` keyword and use *Highlight Usages in File* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>). Then you can use *Find Next* and *Find Previous* to navigate between the occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

in IntelliJ 14.0.3 Community Edition you can do exactly that - place cursor on the class name in import and the occurences of the methods will be like highlighted on the scroll bar.

Comment: Ah Cool. Do you know if there is any shortcut for navigating these results?

Comment: btw, this would only birng up instances of B itself. So if I have private B b=new B(); it would be highlighted but then if later on I have b.function_of_B() this won't be highlighted.

Comment: yes, thank you for the correction, only class name occurrences are highlighted.

as for shortcuts  - maybe something like these: 
Ctrl+F7 - Find usages in file, then F3 - find next

Comment: Essentially what you are doing, is Ctrl+F3 ing, ie a simple find-this-in-the-current-document. Not really what I am asking for.